# Resetting SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server

In a misguided attempt at fixing a database permission issue, I changed the Log On account for my SQL Server from the default (Network Service) to a specific account.  Now the server is stopped and when I try to restart I get: 
"The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion. Consult the event log or other applicable error logs for details."

When I try to change back to Network Service (or to anything else for that matter) I get "Access is denied. [0x80070005]"

I'm signed in as the admin and I'm not working with a cluster which rules out most of what I could google.

I just want to reset it to what it was before, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up and uninstalled and reinstalled SQL Server 2008.  That fixed it.